# Unable to record "Save file" action in Microsoft VSTS

Tags: vb.net

The scenario is to record the following actions:

1. Download an excel file.
2. Save it in the local machine.
3. Edit the file.
4. Upload the edited one into the application.

I tried recording this in VSTS. But didn't happen to see any events or path recorded during the "Save file" action. Eventually upload action is failing.

How do I get through this problem?
Please help.